# Does swagger (in nestjs project) support possibility to pass login/password for basic authentication just from the browser?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have a nestjs project. I use swagger there. It generates documentation and everything is ok. But some of methods require basic authentication and I want to pass credentials closely from the browser. Does swagger support this feature from the box?

I need something similar like Postman has:
[image]

Comment: OpenAPI Specification supports [Basic authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/), and Swagger UI will show the "Authorize" option for endpoints defined as requiring authentication. Check the documentation of your NestJS library to see if it provides annotations to define the authentication method for endpoints.